# Beginner Calculus — Finding the Derivative Before Evaluating

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If you wanted to find $f^{\prime}(x)$ and the value $x$ was known, could you differentiate with $x$ already substituted into the equations, or do you have to keep the $x$ as a variable rather than a constant, find the general derivative, and *then* substitute $x$ into the derivative? If it is the latter, why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

For an exact answer you can differentiate the function, then substitute the value of $x$. However, you could approximate the derivative beforehand using:

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},$$ making $h$ smaller and smaller, and then compare this with your exact answer from differentiation.

But, let's see what happens if we do what you say for a specific example: Suppose $f(x)=x^2$ and $x=1$. Differentiation can be defined by

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Now let $x=1$, then $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2h+h^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}2+h=2.$$

Comment: What if in a different example such as $g(x)=xf(x)$, where $x=1$, $f(1)=3$, and $f^{\prime}(1)=-1$? When differentiating $g(x)$ with the product rule, could you just do $g^{\prime}(1)=[\frac{d}{dx}(1)][3]+[-1][1]$? That would give $g^{\prime}(1)=-1$, while if you were to differentiate without substituting first, then you’d get $g^{\prime}(x)=[1][f(x)]+[f^{\prime}(x)][x]$ and $g^{\prime}(1)=[1][3]+[-1}[1]=2$

Comment: We know that $g'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)$, so if you know for sure the values of $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ for a specific $x$ then yes you can substitute to get the answer - assuming those values are actually correct with respect to $f(x)$.

Comment: But if you substitute it right at the start, then you would have to deal with $x^{\prime}$ in the first term. If you’d already plugged in 1 for x, then the derivative of that becomes 0, and $f(x)$ disappears along with it.

Comment: I’m not given $f(x)$. (I modeled this question closely to a question in my textbook.) If I were given $f(x)$, then does that mean I can substitute directly? And if I’m not, then I can’t?

Comment: You've made a mistake in your calculation: the correct substitutions give $g'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)$, so that $g'(1)=1\cdot(-1)+3=2,$ as required.

Comment: So I have to define $x^{\prime}$ to be $1$. I cannot plug in 1 for x and have $1^{\prime}=0$.

Comment: No. The product rule gives this: $g'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)$. Since $x=1$, $f'(1)=-1$, and $f(1)=3$, then we get $g'(1)=1\cdot f'(1)+f(1)=1\cdot(-1)+3=2$.

Comment: So I _cannot_ substitute directly. I have to differentiate while keeping everything as variables first, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but you may be able to use the limit definition of differentiation to substitute directly. You will have to try that out (similar to as I did in my answer above). But - for the questions you are answering it sounds like you should just differentiate and then substitute at the end. This is the simplest way to do things. Very loosely speaking, the "calculus" kind of abstracts the limit definitions into a neat package which is easier to manipulate for most applications. I liken it to abstraction in object oriented programming, but that's just the way I see it. Good luck.